# CiviCRM Spark: Misconfigured Email Account - Failed to read test message

Tags: civimail, civicrm-spark

I have misconfigured my Email Account on CiviCRM Spark. I tried to restore the settings from memory, unfortunately without success. I get the error message on "Save & Test": Failed to read test message - Directory name must not be empty. (See log for more details.)

Can someone give me the correct default settings?

Comment: Welcome to SE.  If you don't get response here, try the spark channel at https://chat.civicrm.org/

Comment: Hi, I'm a Spark admin and double-checking your settings. They seem OK, but maybe I'm looking at the wrong place. Which menu exactly? Could you post a screenshot?

Comment: Thank you: It is Administer/CiviMail/Mail Accounts

![The screenshot is here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5wlxeyhab9pn8he/Screenshot%202021-12-03%20142604.png?dl=0).

Comment: It seems OK. By default CiviCRM Spark its own email domain for sending emails (civimail.org). I sent myself a test email using CiviMail and it worked correctly. Maybe we can talk over the CiviCRM chat? https://chat.civicrm.org/civicrm/channels/spark